# extract col values from different sheet basis on other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two excel sheets. In excel sheet-1, I have a column `account` which has numbers in it and in excel sheet-2 also I have a column `account` with same and more account numbers in it and it also has more columns like `address` and `city` in it. Now I want to extract `address` and `city` values from sheet-2 for all the accounts that I have in sheet-1. How can we do this either through linux command or in excel?

```
**sheet-1**

account
123456423
987655142
256091212

**sheet-2**

account   colA      colB    colC    address    city
.....
.....
.....
```

Here dots are the values. What is the best way to do this? I am newbie for excel.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` is your best friend here.

Example for address:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$4,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))
```

If you want to be column specific that's possible too:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$F$4,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0),5)
```

And you could even make its range dynamic if nessecary:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX($F:$F,COUNTA($F:$F)),MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0),5)
```

And here something that will do it all for you if you only put this formula in cell `B2` on your sheet1. We can make the column you looking for dynamic too:

Either like specifiying an dynamic INDEX column parametre like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX($F:$F,COUNTA($F:$F)),MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0),COL(E2))
```

Or specifying a dynamic matrix INDEX parametre like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!E$2:INDEX(E:E,COUNTA(E:E)),MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0))
```

Drag it down and to the right.

Obviously there can be even more variation. But this shows how versatile and handy `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` combo really is :)

Comment: can u tell me where I should run this query? It should be in sheet-1 right?

Comment: @flash, yes you want to put these formula where you want to pull the information towards! So if column B in your sheet1 needs to be populated with address, then that's where you put the formula.

Comment: @flash, obviously you need to change the name `Sheet2` in the formula to whatever name you sheet is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify end try:

`=IF(COLUMN()=2,IFERROR(INDEX($J$3:$J$5,MATCH(A3,$I$3:$I$5,0)),"No Address Found"),IF(COLUMN()=3,IFERROR(INDEX($K$3:$K$5,MATCH(A3,$I$3:$I$5,0)),"No City Found")))`

Result:

[image]